# How to split a string to edit only the letters and numbers in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, split

I want to split a string into a list, and separate the letters and numbers from all of the other characters like symbols and spaces.

From here I would want to change all of the letters and numbers, and put them back into a string.

For example, the string

`An example, 200a, many-times...`

would turn into

`['An', ' ', 'example', ', ', '200a', ', ', 'many', '-', 'times', '...']`

Then I could somehow edit only the letter and number ones (An, example, 200a, many, times)
For example turn them backwards and then the final result would be:

`nA elpmaxe, a002, ynam-semit...`

Comment: Show your own effort (code) as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: All I knew how to do was to split the string into a list separated by spaces with `' '.split('string')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible solution might be using regular expression (`re` module in Python) and function [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) (for substitution):

```py
import re

s = 'An example, 200a, many-times...'

def sub_func(g):
    return g.group(0)[::-1]

s = re.sub(r'[a-zA-Z0-9]+', sub_func, s)
print(s)
```

Prints:

```
nA elpmaxe, a002, ynam-semit...
```

Comment: Thanks! I should really learn how regex works...